# How to update XML file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have two XML files that I need to update using Ruby. It would be great if it is done using Nokogiri. Could somebody help me how to do so?

Q1: I need to update `<runName>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><taftasks>
<taftask environment="Local_edu" password="12324" username="edu">
<testsuite name="login">
<rowsToRun>0</rowsToRun>
<runName>Login_Run 201107041433</runName>
<runDescription>ant</runDescription>
</testsuite>
</taftask>
</taftasks>
```

Q2: In the second file I need to change the path for logs. So

```
<property name="reportDir" value="C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds\basics\logs\" />
```

would look like

```
<property name="reportDir" value="C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds\basics\logs\201107060928" />

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- build script for TAF command line execution  
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<project name="Login" default="taf" basedir=".">
-->

<project name="Basics of Edu" default="taf" basedir="C:/Program Files/TestPro/TestPro Automation Framework">
<description>Login_cycle</description>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<property name="testPlan" value="C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds\basics\basics.xml" />
<property name="reportDir" value="C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds\basics\logs\" />
<property name="format" value="csv" />
<property name="category" value="All" />

</project>
```

---

This is the source code related to these questions:

Q1:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri'

file_name = 'C:\web\playground\login.xml'
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file_name))
runName = @doc.at_css "runName"
puts runName.content 
runName.content = "New run name"
puts runName.content
File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.write(@doc) }
```

Q2:
any suggestions how to make the search for `value` one line only?

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri'

file_name = 'C:\web\playground\login_build.xml'
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file_name))

property = @doc.css("property")

property.each {|item|
  if (item['name'] == 'reportDir')
    puts item['value']
    item['value'] = item['value']+'\timestamp'
    puts item['value']
  end
}

File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.write(@doc) }
```

Comment: And what have you tried? A great starting point is [Modifying a HTML/XML document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html).

Comment: my major question is how to find `property name="reportDir"` and then change the value

Comment: Can you write a script to find the property? Then you're most of the way there. Point is, we're not going to do *all* your work for you.

Comment: I tried `@doc = Nokogiri::Slop(File.open(file_name))
puts  @doc.project.property("[@name='reportDir']").content` but it gives me `.../slop.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `project' for #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x2b93200> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: any idea why `Slop` didn't work for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q1:

Replace:

```
File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.write(@doc) }
```

with:

```
File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.puts @doc.to_xml }
```

Or better:

```
File.write(file_name, @doc.to_xml)
```

You don't want the object `@doc`, you want its XML representation.

Q2:

```
property = @doc.css("property")
```

should be:

```
property = @doc.at('property[name="reportDir"]')
```

You want only that particular node so look for it explicitly.

Replace:

```
property.each {|item|
  if (item['name'] == 'reportDir')
    puts item['value']
    item['value'] = item['value']+'\timestamp'
    puts item['value']
  end
}
```

with:

```
property['value'] = property['value'] + 'timestamp'
```

Replace:

```
File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.write(@doc) }
```

with:

```
File.open(file_name, 'w') {|f| f.puts @doc.to_xml }
```

Again, you don't want the object `@doc`, you want its XML representation.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I don't understand the `XML representation`. It works now at it is, it's been tested. I read it as XML so @doc is xml, isn't it.

Comment: @doc is not XML. It is an object that represents the parsed XML DOM. You are relying on Nokogiri's behavior of outputting XML when the object is converted to a string. Rather than rely on the default behavior, be explicit for safety; That way, Nokogiri's default behavior can change and your code will continue to work correctly.